# Avoid creation of object wrapper type/value in MOXy (JAXB+JSON)

Tags: java, json, jaxb, moxy

I'm using MOXy 2.6 (JAXB+JSON).

I want ObjectElement and StringElement to be marshalled the same way, but MOXy creates wrapper object when fields are typed as Object.

**ObjectElement.java**

```
public class ObjectElement {
    public Object testVar = "testValue";
}
```

**StringElement.java**

```
public class StringElement {
    public String testVar = "testValue";
}
```

**Demo.java**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.MediaType;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] { ObjectElement.class, StringElement.class }, null);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        System.out.println("ObjectElement:");
        ObjectElement objectElement = new ObjectElement();
        marshaller.marshal(objectElement, System.out);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("StringElement:");
        StringElement stringElement = new StringElement();
        marshaller.marshal(stringElement, System.out);
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

When launching **Demo.java**, here's the output ...

```
ObjectElement:
{"testVar":{"type":"string","value":"testValue"}}
StringElement:
{"testVar":"testValue"}
```

How to configure MOXy/JaxB to make ObjectElement render as StringElement object ? How to avoid the creation of object wrapper with *"type"* and *"value"* properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the Annotation `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute`. This will render ObjectElement and StringElement to the same output.

See the following example:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class ObjectElement {
    @XmlAttribute
    public Object testVar = "testValue";
}
```

I've used the following [test class](https://github.com/AndreasAumayr/stackoverflow/blob/master/JSON-Moxy/src/test/java/at/aumand/stackoverflow/question30646707/JsonTest.java) to verify the correct behaviour.

EDIT after the question was updated:

Yes it's possible. Instead of using XmlAttribute like before, I switched to `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement` in combination with a type attribute.

The class is now declared as:

```
public class ObjectElement {
  @XmlElement(type = String.class)
  public Object testVar = "testValue";
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other solution ? I wish it also work with XML without creating an Attribute, but value to be text content of <testVar>testValue</testVar>.

Comment: yes it's possible. see my updated answer as well as the sample code on github.